# Strange behavior if condition

Tags: c, cs50

i am self taught programmer
i face a problem here that if condition to enter only  ( H OR T OR . )
doesn't get the string . go to the (`printf ("Enter valid characters please  \n");`)

below is my code :

```
int i = 0 ;
int L ;

printf ("Please enter the lenght of report \n"); 
scanf ("%d" , &L);

if ( L>=1 && L<=500 )
{
        printf ("Please enter the Reoprt \n");
        string P = get_string ();
        if (P[i] !='H' && P[i] != 'T' && P[i] != '.')
        {
                printf ("Enter valid characters please  \n");
        }
        else 
        {
                printf ("GOOD3 \n");
        }
}
else 
{
        printf ("Please enter valid Length \n"); 
}
```

Comment: how is `i` treated?

Comment: Is this `C`? What does `string P` does? What `get_string()` function does?

Comment: @GauravPathak cs50.h, yes we all hate it. It is typedefed to char*.

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you show? For some example input, what is the expected and actual output? Have you tried stepping through the code line by line while monitoring variables in a debugger?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude (_being sarcastic_) why? aren't you suppose to do my work for me? for free? :P

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I heard about `cs50.h` for the first time.
Thanks!

Comment: Even if you are self-taught, you have heard about *loops*? It seems that's what you're looking for. And a [good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: What is the issue? [Demo](https://ideone.com/ive1AB) works fine in my opinion? Are you compiling your code before running? (Assuming you want to check if the report begins with H or T or .)

Comment: The main problem is in `scanf `when i use cs50 functions the code runs well . I will try to focus more on the problem Thank you all

Comment: off topic:  when the user runs this program, all the user sees is "Please enter the lenght of report" with a blinking cursor on the second line.  You should always tell the user what they are expected to do. (BTW: `lenght` should be: `length`)  Suggest: the prompt be: "Please enter the length of report (range: 1...500 inclusive)".  Similar considerations exist for "Please enter the Reoprt" (BTW: `Reoprt` should be: `Report`) where the only valid characters are: `H`, `T`, and `.`   When ever there is a problem with the input, output a error message and loop to try again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're having this problem is because `scanf("%d", &L)` will fetch one or more digits from the input *and nothing else*. As a result, it will leave behind the newline character that you entered after typing in your number.

When you call `get_string()` (I assume this is the same as `GetString()` in the CS50 library?), the first character it sees is this residual newline character, so all you're getting back is an empty string.

You can fix this easily enough. Just replace `scanf ("%d" , &L);` with `L = GetInt();`.

Or, alternatively, replace `scanf ("%d" , &L);` with `scanf ("%d%c" , &L, &newline);`, with `newline` declared as a `char` variable at the top of your `main()` function. This will consume the line break that follows the number, so that `GetString()` won't treat it as an empty string. For more details on how `scanf()` works, type `man scanf` at the command line.